# Update a single container in an Azure container instance with multiple container

Tags: azure-container-instances

We've got an Azure container instance running in Azure with multiple containers deployed to it (via a yaml file). When we run updates, we have to run the full yaml file every time, with some of the values (i.e. image id) amended.

We'd like to break up our code so that we have more of a microservice approach to development (separate repos, separate devops pipelines).  Is it possible to instruct a container instance to update one container (from a set of 4 for example) without submitting values for all containers?

For example, if we could have each repo contain a pipeline that only updates one instance in the aci it would be great.  Note, what I think might happen is that we may get an error when submitting an update for one container because aci thinks we are trying to raise 3 containers and update one of them (if we have a group of 4).

If it's not possible, is there any other way of achieving the same, without having to step up to Kubernetes?  Ideally we'd like to not have to use Kubernetes just because of the management overhead required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update a single container in a container group. All containers will restart whenever any part of the group is updated.

Every container you want to update separately needs to be in its own group. If you split the containers, the containers will no longer be running on the same host and you will lose the ability to access the other services via localhost (you will have to use the DNS name of the container group).

If some of your containers serve endpoints that are exposed as paths of a single server, you will need to set up something like Azure Front Door to enable path-based routing so traffic can hit the correct service via a single hostname.